# How to get rid of null values from a String of array in java?

Tags: java, string

I am trying to remove duplicates from my list and then trying to save it in a String Array. However i want to eliminate if there is a empty value i.e. "" but my if condition does not seem to work it still display a blank in the output. How can i get rid of it ? I am expecting an overall size of 8 elements after ignoring the blank value

```
Output:Printing Set                              Peardonville and South Fraser

Printing Set                                     Clearbrook and South Fraser

Printing Set                                     George Ferguson and Gladwin

Printing Set                                     Ar. Bourquin Exchange

Printing Set                                     Lv. Bourquin Exchange

Printing Set                                     Downtown Abbotsford

Printing Set                                     Marshall and McCallum

Printing Set                                     University of the Fraser Valley

**Printing Set**
```

Size of StopNamesForDB is = 9

```
    Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>(StopNames); 
    System.out.println("Size of Set Object" + set.size()); 
    StopNamesForDB = new String[set.size()];

        for (String string : set) {

            if(string.equals(" ")){

            } 
            else{ 
            System.out.println("Printing Set " + string); 
            StopNamesForDB[i] = string; 
            i++; 
             } 
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing array like:

```
String [] StopNamesForDB = new String[set.size()];
```

By doing this, size of StopNamesForDB array will always be 9, irrespective you add element to it or not.

Also, please note that you are checking for a space in your code:

```
if(string.equals(" ")){
```

Please change it to below code or trim it:

```
if(string.equals("")){
```

Thanks, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`trim`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) method: `if(string.trim().isEmpty())`

Comment: Always check for NPE  if(string!=null){              if(string.trim().isEmpty()) {}                                                }

Comment: You don't always have to be defensive. Maybe he created ``StopNames`` just before without any ``null``... And it is not really the point here.

Comment: Its just a suggestion and a standard practice. It will only make code safe.

Answer (score 1):

In if condition, try this:

```
if ( string.trim().equals("") ){

}
else{
     //Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 List<String> toRemove = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String string : set) {

            if(string.isEmpty()){
                  toRemove.add(string);

            } 
}
```

then remove all the matched objects from your set.

```
for(String string: toRemove)
       set.remove(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about List or Set.
Set does not  allow duplicate values so do not worry about duplicates ...

If you want to filter  " " use
if (string != null && string.trim().length() > 0){
}

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, since you intent only to discard the empty ones.

```
   for (String string : set) {
        if (string != null && string.trim().length() > 0) {
            System.out.println("Printing Set " + string);
            StopNamesForDB[i] = string;
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your codition

```
if(string.equals(" ")){

            }
```

to

```
if(string.trim().length == 0){

            }
```

it will work :)